# Vacation/autoreply messages with postfix and Roundcube

Tags: debian, postfix, email-server, roundcube, auto-reply

How to set up vacation/autoreply messages when using postfix + virtual_aliases in MySQL and Roundcube as a frontend?

Is there any step-by-step guide?

I've been trying to set up [feurix/response](https://github.com/feurix/response), but with no luck:

- debug messages says that the mail is sent, info stored in MySQL (but not delivered to sender acutally)

Sending to `totest@example.com`, debug message:

```
Response record successful!
Jan 25 01:17:44 v2704 postfix/lmtp[21656]: A8BD6201B5E: to=<totest#example.com@response.internal>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=0.09, delays=0.07/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok)
```

What's this [response.internal](https://github.com/feurix/response/blob/master/examples/POSTFIX.conf)?

- Roundcube plugin does not save the settings (just reloads the page)

Comment: Double check your crontab is configured properly as described in the INSTALL document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the installation instructions carefully. I have tested both of the scripts (python and Roundcube) and they work just fine.

If the responses are properly stored in `autoreply_record` table and the vacation notification are not being sent, Double check you are properly running `/opt/response/response-notify` script in crontab.

If the Roundcube plugin settings are not properly saved, double check your database connection settings in the plugin config file.